# Chart.js How to predefine 24 H time labels on x AXIS

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I want to show 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00, 23:59 on x axis with data in between the times.
I am working with this:
[image: Chart looks]

And I would like to do it like this:
[image: chart]

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("heat-pump-chart");

    heatPumpChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{"data":[{"x":"17:19:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:20:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:20:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:20:39","y":48.7},{"x":"17:20:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:21:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:21:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:21:39","y":48.7},{"x":"17:21:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:22:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:22:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:22:39","y":48.7},{"x":"17:22:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:23:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:23:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:23:39","y":48.7},{"x":"17:23:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:24:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:24:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:24:39","y":48.7},{"x":"17:24:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:25:09","y":48.7},{"x":"17:25:48","y":48.7},{"x":"17:25:54","y":48.7},{"x":"17:26:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:26:24","y":48.7},{"x":"17:26:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:26:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:27:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:27:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:27:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:27:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:28:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:28:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:28:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:28:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:29:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:29:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:29:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:29:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:30:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:30:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:30:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:30:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:31:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:31:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:31:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:31:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:32:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:32:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:32:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:32:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:33:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:33:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:33:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:34:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:34:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:34:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:35:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:35:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:35:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:36:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:36:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:36:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:36:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:37:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:37:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:37:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:37:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:38:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:38:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:38:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:38:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:39:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:39:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:39:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:39:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:40:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:40:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:40:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:40:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:41:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:41:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:41:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:41:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:42:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:42:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:42:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:42:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:43:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:43:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:43:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:43:55","y":48.7},{"x":"17:44:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:44:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:44:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:44:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:45:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:45:25","y":48.7},{"x":"17:45:40","y":48.7},{"x":"17:45:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:46:10","y":48.7},{"x":"17:46:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:46:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:46:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:47:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:47:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:47:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:47:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:48:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:48:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:48:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:48:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:49:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:49:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:49:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:49:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:50:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:50:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:50:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:50:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:51:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:51:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:51:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:51:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:52:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:52:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:52:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:52:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:53:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:53:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:53:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:53:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:54:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:54:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:54:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:54:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:55:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:55:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:55:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:55:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:56:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:56:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:56:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:56:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:57:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:57:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:57:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:57:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:58:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:58:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:58:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:58:55","y":48.6},{"x":"17:59:10","y":48.6},{"x":"17:59:25","y":48.6},{"x":"17:59:40","y":48.6},{"x":"17:59:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:00:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:00:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:00:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:00:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:01:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:01:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:01:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:01:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:02:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:02:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:02:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:02:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:03:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:03:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:03:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:03:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:04:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:04:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:04:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:04:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:05:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:05:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:05:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:05:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:06:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:06:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:06:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:06:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:07:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:07:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:07:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:07:56","y":48.6},{"x":"18:08:11","y":48.6},{"x":"18:08:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:08:41","y":48.6},{"x":"18:08:56","y":48.5},{"x":"18:09:11","y":48.5},{"x":"18:09:26","y":48.6},{"x":"18:09:41","y":48.5},{"x":"18:09:56","y":48.5},{"x":"18:10:11","y":48.6}],"label":"Water Temp (°C)","fill":true,"borderWidth":1},{"data":[{"x":"17:19:55","y":44.5},{"x":"17:20:09","y":44.5},{"x":"17:20:24","y":44.5},{"x":"17:20:39","y":44.6},{"x":"17:20:54","y":44.6},{"x":"17:21:09","y":44.6},{"x":"17:21:24","y":44.7},{"x":"17:21:39","y":44.7},{"x":"17:21:54","y":44.7},{"x":"17:22:09","y":44.7},{"x":"17:22:24","y":44.8},{"x":"17:22:39","y":44.8},{"x":"17:22:54","y":44.8},{"x":"17:23:09","y":45},{"x":"17:23:24","y":45},{"x":"17:23:39","y":45},{"x":"17:23:54","y":45},{"x":"17:24:09","y":45.1},{"x":"17:24:24","y":45.1},{"x":"17:24:39","y":45.2},{"x":"17:24:54","y":45.2},{"x":"17:25:09","y":45.2},{"x":"17:25:48","y":45.4},{"x":"17:25:54","y":45.4},{"x":"17:26:10","y":45.4},{"x":"17:26:24","y":45.5},{"x":"17:26:40","y":45.5},{"x":"17:26:55","y":45.5},{"x":"17:27:10","y":45.6},{"x":"17:27:25","y":45.6},{"x":"17:27:40","y":45.6},{"x":"17:27:55","y":45.7},{"x":"17:28:10","y":45.7},{"x":"17:28:25","y":45.7},{"x":"17:28:40","y":45.9},{"x":"17:28:55","y":45.9},{"x":"17:29:10","y":45.9},{"x":"17:29:25","y":46},{"x":"17:29:40","y":46},{"x":"17:29:55","y":46.1},{"x":"17:30:10","y":46.1},{"x":"17:30:25","y":46.1},{"x":"17:30:40","y":46.1},{"x":"17:30:55","y":46.1},{"x":"17:31:10","y":46.2},{"x":"17:31:25","y":46.2},{"x":"17:31:40","y":46.4},{"x":"17:31:55","y":46.4},{"x":"17:32:10","y":46.4},{"x":"17:32:25","y":46.4},{"x":"17:32:40","y":46.4},{"x":"17:32:55","y":46.4},{"x":"17:33:10","y":46.5},{"x":"17:33:25","y":46.5},{"x":"17:33:55","y":46.6},{"x":"17:34:10","y":46.5},{"x":"17:34:25","y":46.6},{"x":"17:34:40","y":46.8},{"x":"17:35:25","y":46.8},{"x":"17:35:40","y":46.8},{"x":"17:35:55","y":46.8},{"x":"17:36:10","y":46.8},{"x":"17:36:25","y":46.8},{"x":"17:36:40","y":46.9},{"x":"17:36:55","y":46.9},{"x":"17:37:10","y":46.8},{"x":"17:37:25","y":46.6},{"x":"17:37:40","y":46.6},{"x":"17:37:55","y":46.6},{"x":"17:38:10","y":46.4},{"x":"17:38:25","y":46.1},{"x":"17:38:40","y":45.9},{"x":"17:38:55","y":45.7},{"x":"17:39:10","y":45.4},{"x":"17:39:25","y":45.2},{"x":"17:39:40","y":45},{"x":"17:39:55","y":44.7},{"x":"17:40:10","y":44.6},{"x":"17:40:25","y":44.6},{"x":"17:40:40","y":44.4},{"x":"17:40:55","y":44.1},{"x":"17:41:10","y":43.9},{"x":"17:41:25","y":43.6},{"x":"17:41:40","y":43.2},{"x":"17:41:55","y":43},{"x":"17:42:10","y":43.1},{"x":"17:42:25","y":43.2},{"x":"17:42:40","y":43.2},{"x":"17:42:55","y":43.2},{"x":"17:43:10","y":43.2},{"x":"17:43:25","y":43.4},{"x":"17:43:40","y":43.5},{"x":"17:43:55","y":43.6},{"x":"17:44:10","y":43.7},{"x":"17:44:25","y":43.9},{"x":"17:44:40","y":43.9},{"x":"17:44:55","y":44},{"x":"17:45:10","y":44},{"x":"17:45:25","y":44.1},{"x":"17:45:40","y":44.1},{"x":"17:45:55","y":44.1},{"x":"17:46:10","y":44.2},{"x":"17:46:25","y":44.2},{"x":"17:46:40","y":44.2},{"x":"17:46:55","y":44.4},{"x":"17:47:10","y":44.5},{"x":"17:47:25","y":44.5},{"x":"17:47:40","y":44.6},{"x":"17:47:55","y":44.6},{"x":"17:48:10","y":44.7},{"x":"17:48:25","y":44.7},{"x":"17:48:40","y":44.8},{"x":"17:48:55","y":44.8},{"x":"17:49:10","y":45},{"x":"17:49:25","y":45},{"x":"17:49:40","y":45.1},{"x":"17:49:55","y":45.1},{"x":"17:50:10","y":45.1},{"x":"17:50:25","y":45.1},{"x":"17:50:40","y":45.2},{"x":"17:50:55","y":45.2},{"x":"17:51:10","y":45.4},{"x":"17:51:25","y":45.4},{"x":"17:51:40","y":45.5},{"x":"17:51:55","y":45.5},{"x":"17:52:10","y":45.5},{"x":"17:52:25","y":45.5},{"x":"17:52:40","y":45.6},{"x":"17:52:55","y":45.6},{"x":"17:53:10","y":45.6},{"x":"17:53:25","y":45.7},{"x":"17:53:40","y":45.7},{"x":"17:53:55","y":45.7},{"x":"17:54:10","y":45.7},{"x":"17:54:25","y":45.9},{"x":"17:54:40","y":45.9},{"x":"17:54:55","y":45.9},{"x":"17:55:10","y":46},{"x":"17:55:25","y":46},{"x":"17:55:40","y":46},{"x":"17:55:55","y":46},{"x":"17:56:10","y":46.1},{"x":"17:56:25","y":46.1},{"x":"17:56:40","y":46.1},{"x":"17:56:55","y":46.2},{"x":"17:57:10","y":46.2},{"x":"17:57:25","y":46.2},{"x":"17:57:40","y":46.2},{"x":"17:57:55","y":46.4},{"x":"17:58:10","y":46.4},{"x":"17:58:25","y":46.4},{"x":"17:58:40","y":46.4},{"x":"17:58:55","y":46.5},{"x":"17:59:10","y":46.6},{"x":"17:59:25","y":46.6},{"x":"17:59:40","y":46.6},{"x":"17:59:56","y":46.6},{"x":"18:00:11","y":46.8},{"x":"18:00:26","y":46.8},{"x":"18:00:41","y":46.8},{"x":"18:00:56","y":46.8},{"x":"18:01:11","y":46.9},{"x":"18:01:26","y":46.9},{"x":"18:01:41","y":46.9},{"x":"18:01:56","y":46.9},{"x":"18:02:11","y":46.9},{"x":"18:02:26","y":46.9},{"x":"18:02:41","y":46.8},{"x":"18:02:56","y":46.8},{"x":"18:03:11","y":46.8},{"x":"18:03:26","y":46.6},{"x":"18:03:41","y":46.6},{"x":"18:03:56","y":46.6},{"x":"18:04:11","y":46.5},{"x":"18:04:26","y":46.5},{"x":"18:04:41","y":46.5},{"x":"18:04:56","y":46.5},{"x":"18:05:11","y":46.4},{"x":"18:05:26","y":46.4},{"x":"18:05:41","y":46.4},{"x":"18:05:56","y":46.5},{"x":"18:06:11","y":46.5},{"x":"18:06:26","y":46.4},{"x":"18:06:41","y":46.4},{"x":"18:06:56","y":46.4},{"x":"18:07:11","y":46.4},{"x":"18:07:26","y":46.4},{"x":"18:07:41","y":46.4},{"x":"18:07:56","y":46.4},{"x":"18:08:11","y":46.4},{"x":"18:08:26","y":46.4},{"x":"18:08:41","y":46.4},{"x":"18:08:56","y":46.4},{"x":"18:09:11","y":46.4},{"x":"18:09:26","y":46.2},{"x":"18:09:41","y":46.2},{"x":"18:09:56","y":46.2},{"x":"18:10:11","y":46.4}],"label":"Heating Temp (°C)","fill":true,"borderWidth":1},{"data":[{"x":"17:19:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:20:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:20:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:20:39","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:20:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:21:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:21:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:21:39","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:21:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:22:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:22:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:22:39","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:22:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:23:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:23:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:23:39","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:23:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:24:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:24:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:24:39","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:24:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:25:09","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:25:48","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:25:54","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:26:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:26:24","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:26:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:26:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:27:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:27:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:27:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:27:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:28:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:28:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:28:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:28:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:29:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:29:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:29:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:29:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:30:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:30:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:30:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:30:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:31:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:31:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:31:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:31:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:32:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:32:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:32:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:32:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:33:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:33:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:33:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:34:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:34:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:34:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:35:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:35:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:35:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:36:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:36:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:36:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:36:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:37:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:37:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:37:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:37:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:38:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:38:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:38:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:38:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:39:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:39:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:39:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:39:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:40:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:40:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:40:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:40:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:41:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:41:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:41:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:41:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:42:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:42:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:42:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:42:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:43:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:43:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:43:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:43:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:44:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:44:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:44:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:44:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:45:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:45:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:45:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:45:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:46:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:46:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:46:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:46:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:47:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:47:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:47:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:47:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:48:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:48:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:48:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:48:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:49:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:49:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:49:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:49:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:50:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:50:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:50:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:50:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:51:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:51:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:51:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:51:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:52:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:52:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:52:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:52:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:53:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:53:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:53:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:53:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:54:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:54:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:54:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:54:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:55:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:55:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:55:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:55:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:56:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:56:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:56:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:56:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:57:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:57:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:57:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:57:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:58:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:58:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:58:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:58:55","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:59:10","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:59:25","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:59:40","y":-2.8},{"x":"17:59:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:00:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:00:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:00:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:00:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:01:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:01:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:01:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:01:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:02:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:02:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:02:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:02:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:03:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:03:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:03:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:03:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:04:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:04:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:04:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:04:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:05:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:05:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:05:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:05:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:06:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:06:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:06:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:06:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:07:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:07:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:07:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:07:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:08:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:08:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:08:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:08:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:09:11","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:09:26","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:09:41","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:09:56","y":-2.8},{"x":"18:10:11","y":-2.8}],"label":"Outside Temp (°C)","fill":true,"borderWidth":1},{"data":[{"x":"17:19:55","y":101.9},{"x":"17:20:09","y":102.2},{"x":"17:20:24","y":102.2},{"x":"17:20:39","y":102.4},{"x":"17:20:54","y":102.4},{"x":"17:21:09","y":102.4},{"x":"17:21:24","y":102.9},{"x":"17:21:39","y":102.9},{"x":"17:21:54","y":103.1},{"x":"17:22:09","y":103.1},{"x":"17:22:24","y":103.3},{"x":"17:22:39","y":103.6},{"x":"17:22:54","y":103.3},{"x":"17:23:09","y":103.6},{"x":"17:23:24","y":103.6},{"x":"17:23:39","y":103.8},{"x":"17:23:54","y":103.8},{"x":"17:24:09","y":104.1},{"x":"17:24:24","y":104.1},{"x":"17:24:39","y":104.3},{"x":"17:24:54","y":104.5},{"x":"17:25:09","y":104.5},{"x":"17:25:48","y":105},{"x":"17:25:54","y":104.8},{"x":"17:26:10","y":105},{"x":"17:26:24","y":105.3},{"x":"17:26:40","y":105.3},{"x":"17:26:55","y":105.3},{"x":"17:27:10","y":105.5},{"x":"17:27:25","y":105.5},{"x":"17:27:40","y":105.5},{"x":"17:27:55","y":105.8},{"x":"17:28:10","y":106.1},{"x":"17:28:25","y":106.1},{"x":"17:28:40","y":106.3},{"x":"17:28:55","y":106.3},{"x":"17:29:10","y":106.3},{"x":"17:29:25","y":106.6},{"x":"17:29:40","y":106.6},{"x":"17:29:55","y":106.9},{"x":"17:30:10","y":106.9},{"x":"17:30:25","y":107.1},{"x":"17:30:40","y":107.1},{"x":"17:30:55","y":107.1},{"x":"17:31:10","y":107.4},{"x":"17:31:25","y":107.4},{"x":"17:31:40","y":107.7},{"x":"17:31:55","y":107.7},{"x":"17:32:10","y":107.7},{"x":"17:32:25","y":107.7},{"x":"17:32:40","y":107.9},{"x":"17:32:55","y":107.9},{"x":"17:33:10","y":108.2},{"x":"17:33:25","y":108.2},{"x":"17:33:55","y":108.4},{"x":"17:34:10","y":108.4},{"x":"17:34:25","y":108.7},{"x":"17:34:40","y":108.7},{"x":"17:35:25","y":109},{"x":"17:35:40","y":109},{"x":"17:35:55","y":109.2},{"x":"17:36:10","y":109.2},{"x":"17:36:25","y":109.2},{"x":"17:36:40","y":109.2},{"x":"17:36:55","y":109.2},{"x":"17:37:10","y":109.5},{"x":"17:37:25","y":109.2},{"x":"17:37:40","y":100.7},{"x":"17:37:55","y":92.4},{"x":"17:38:10","y":86.8},{"x":"17:38:25","y":82.9},{"x":"17:38:40","y":79.9},{"x":"17:38:55","y":78.2},{"x":"17:39:10","y":76.4},{"x":"17:39:25","y":75},{"x":"17:39:40","y":74.1},{"x":"17:39:55","y":73.5},{"x":"17:40:10","y":73.2},{"x":"17:40:25","y":73.1},{"x":"17:40:40","y":73},{"x":"17:40:55","y":72.8},{"x":"17:41:10","y":72.7},{"x":"17:41:25","y":72.6},{"x":"17:41:40","y":75.6},{"x":"17:41:55","y":79.6},{"x":"17:42:10","y":82.7},{"x":"17:42:25","y":82.7},{"x":"17:42:40","y":81.2},{"x":"17:42:55","y":80.6},{"x":"17:43:10","y":79.8},{"x":"17:43:25","y":78.3},{"x":"17:43:40","y":76.5},{"x":"17:43:55","y":74.9},{"x":"17:44:10","y":73.7},{"x":"17:44:25","y":72.3},{"x":"17:44:40","y":71.2},{"x":"17:44:55","y":70.1},{"x":"17:45:10","y":69.5},{"x":"17:45:25","y":68.8},{"x":"17:45:40","y":68.5},{"x":"17:45:55","y":68.5},{"x":"17:46:10","y":68.9},{"x":"17:46:25","y":69.6},{"x":"17:46:40","y":70.4},{"x":"17:46:55","y":71.3},{"x":"17:47:10","y":72.3},{"x":"17:47:25","y":73.4},{"x":"17:47:40","y":74.7},{"x":"17:47:55","y":76.1},{"x":"17:48:10","y":77.6},{"x":"17:48:25","y":79},{"x":"17:48:40","y":80.4},{"x":"17:48:55","y":81.9},{"x":"17:49:10","y":83.4},{"x":"17:49:25","y":84.6},{"x":"17:49:40","y":85.9},{"x":"17:49:55","y":87},{"x":"17:50:10","y":88},{"x":"17:50:25","y":89.1},{"x":"17:50:40","y":90},{"x":"17:50:55","y":90.6},{"x":"17:51:10","y":91.6},{"x":"17:51:25","y":92.4},{"x":"17:51:40","y":93},{"x":"17:51:55","y":93.6},{"x":"17:52:10","y":94.2},{"x":"17:52:25","y":94.5},{"x":"17:52:40","y":94.9},{"x":"17:52:55","y":95.6},{"x":"17:53:10","y":96},{"x":"17:53:25","y":96.7},{"x":"17:53:40","y":97.2},{"x":"17:53:55","y":97.6},{"x":"17:54:10","y":98.3},{"x":"17:54:25","y":98.9},{"x":"17:54:40","y":99.1},{"x":"17:54:55","y":99.3},{"x":"17:55:10","y":99.6},{"x":"17:55:25","y":99.6},{"x":"17:55:40","y":99.6},{"x":"17:55:55","y":99.8},{"x":"17:56:10","y":100},{"x":"17:56:25","y":100.2},{"x":"17:56:40","y":100.5},{"x":"17:56:55","y":100.7},{"x":"17:57:10","y":101.2},{"x":"17:57:25","y":101.7},{"x":"17:57:40","y":101.9},{"x":"17:57:55","y":102.2},{"x":"17:58:10","y":102.4},{"x":"17:58:25","y":102.4},{"x":"17:58:40","y":102.4},{"x":"17:58:55","y":102.4},{"x":"17:59:10","y":102.6},{"x":"17:59:25","y":102.9},{"x":"17:59:40","y":102.9},{"x":"17:59:56","y":103.1},{"x":"18:00:11","y":103.3},{"x":"18:00:26","y":103.8},{"x":"18:00:41","y":104.1},{"x":"18:00:56","y":104.3},{"x":"18:01:11","y":104.3},{"x":"18:01:26","y":104.3},{"x":"18:01:41","y":104.5},{"x":"18:01:56","y":104.5},{"x":"18:02:11","y":104.5},{"x":"18:02:26","y":104.5},{"x":"18:02:41","y":104.8},{"x":"18:02:56","y":104.8},{"x":"18:03:11","y":105.3},{"x":"18:03:26","y":105.5},{"x":"18:03:41","y":105.8},{"x":"18:03:56","y":106.1},{"x":"18:04:11","y":106.3},{"x":"18:04:26","y":106.3},{"x":"18:04:41","y":106.3},{"x":"18:04:56","y":106.6},{"x":"18:05:11","y":106.6},{"x":"18:05:26","y":106.9},{"x":"18:05:41","y":106.9},{"x":"18:05:56","y":107.1},{"x":"18:06:11","y":107.1},{"x":"18:06:26","y":107.7},{"x":"18:06:41","y":107.9},{"x":"18:06:56","y":108.2},{"x":"18:07:11","y":108.2},{"x":"18:07:26","y":108.4},{"x":"18:07:41","y":108.4},{"x":"18:07:56","y":108.4},{"x":"18:08:11","y":108.7},{"x":"18:08:26","y":108.7},{"x":"18:08:41","y":109},{"x":"18:08:56","y":109},{"x":"18:09:11","y":109.2},{"x":"18:09:26","y":109.5},{"x":"18:09:41","y":109.7},{"x":"18:09:56","y":110},{"x":"18:10:11","y":110.3}],"label":"Hot Gas Temp (°C)","fill":true,"borderWidth":1},{"data":[{"x":"17:19:55","y":42.9},{"x":"17:20:09","y":43.1},{"x":"17:20:24","y":43},{"x":"17:20:39","y":42.9},{"x":"17:20:54","y":43.1},{"x":"17:21:09","y":43.2},{"x":"17:21:24","y":43.2},{"x":"17:21:39","y":43.2},{"x":"17:21:54","y":43.2},{"x":"17:22:09","y":43.1},{"x":"17:22:24","y":43.2},{"x":"17:22:39","y":43.2},{"x":"17:22:54","y":43.4},{"x":"17:23:09","y":43.2},{"x":"17:23:24","y":43.4},{"x":"17:23:39","y":43.5},{"x":"17:23:54","y":43.6},{"x":"17:24:09","y":43.7},{"x":"17:24:24","y":43.9},{"x":"17:24:39","y":43.7},{"x":"17:24:54","y":43.7},{"x":"17:25:09","y":43.9},{"x":"17:25:48","y":43.9},{"x":"17:25:54","y":44},{"x":"17:26:10","y":44},{"x":"17:26:24","y":43.7},{"x":"17:26:40","y":44.1},{"x":"17:26:55","y":44},{"x":"17:27:10","y":44.2},{"x":"17:27:25","y":44.2},{"x":"17:27:40","y":44.1},{"x":"17:27:55","y":44.2},{"x":"17:28:10","y":44.4},{"x":"17:28:25","y":44.5},{"x":"17:28:40","y":44.5},{"x":"17:28:55","y":44.5},{"x":"17:29:10","y":44.5},{"x":"17:29:25","y":44.2},{"x":"17:29:40","y":44.5},{"x":"17:29:55","y":44.6},{"x":"17:30:10","y":44.6},{"x":"17:30:25","y":44.6},{"x":"17:30:40","y":44.6},{"x":"17:30:55","y":44.7},{"x":"17:31:10","y":44.7},{"x":"17:31:25","y":44.6},{"x":"17:31:40","y":44.7},{"x":"17:31:55","y":44.5},{"x":"17:32:10","y":44.7},{"x":"17:32:25","y":44.8},{"x":"17:32:40","y":44.8},{"x":"17:32:55","y":44.7},{"x":"17:33:10","y":44.8},{"x":"17:33:25","y":44.8},{"x":"17:33:55","y":45.1},{"x":"17:34:10","y":45},{"x":"17:34:25","y":45},{"x":"17:34:40","y":45},{"x":"17:35:25","y":45.1},{"x":"17:35:40","y":45},{"x":"17:35:55","y":45.4},{"x":"17:36:10","y":45.2},{"x":"17:36:25","y":45.1},{"x":"17:36:40","y":45.2},{"x":"17:36:55","y":45.2},{"x":"17:37:10","y":45.5},{"x":"17:37:25","y":45.5},{"x":"17:37:40","y":45.5},{"x":"17:37:55","y":45.7},{"x":"17:38:10","y":45.6},{"x":"17:38:25","y":45.4},{"x":"17:38:40","y":45.1},{"x":"17:38:55","y":44.7},{"x":"17:39:10","y":44.7},{"x":"17:39:25","y":44.7},{"x":"17:39:40","y":44.4},{"x":"17:39:55","y":44.1},{"x":"17:40:10","y":44.1},{"x":"17:40:25","y":44},{"x":"17:40:40","y":43.9},{"x":"17:40:55","y":43.9},{"x":"17:41:10","y":43.7},{"x":"17:41:25","y":43.5},{"x":"17:41:40","y":43.5},{"x":"17:41:55","y":43.1},{"x":"17:42:10","y":43.1},{"x":"17:42:25","y":43.1},{"x":"17:42:40","y":42.8},{"x":"17:42:55","y":42.5},{"x":"17:43:10","y":42.6},{"x":"17:43:25","y":42.5},{"x":"17:43:40","y":42.5},{"x":"17:43:55","y":42.6},{"x":"17:44:10","y":42.6},{"x":"17:44:25","y":42.6},{"x":"17:44:40","y":42.8},{"x":"17:44:55","y":42.9},{"x":"17:45:10","y":42.8},{"x":"17:45:25","y":42.8},{"x":"17:45:40","y":43},{"x":"17:45:55","y":43.1},{"x":"17:46:10","y":43},{"x":"17:46:25","y":43.1},{"x":"17:46:40","y":43.2},{"x":"17:46:55","y":43.1},{"x":"17:47:10","y":43.2},{"x":"17:47:25","y":43.1},{"x":"17:47:40","y":43.2},{"x":"17:47:55","y":43.2},{"x":"17:48:10","y":43.2},{"x":"17:48:25","y":43.4},{"x":"17:48:40","y":43.5},{"x":"17:48:55","y":43.6},{"x":"17:49:10","y":43.5},{"x":"17:49:25","y":43.5},{"x":"17:49:40","y":43.6},{"x":"17:49:55","y":43.9},{"x":"17:50:10","y":43.9},{"x":"17:50:25","y":43.9},{"x":"17:50:40","y":43.7},{"x":"17:50:55","y":43.9},{"x":"17:51:10","y":44.1},{"x":"17:51:25","y":43.7},{"x":"17:51:40","y":43.7},{"x":"17:51:55","y":44.2},{"x":"17:52:10","y":44.2},{"x":"17:52:25","y":44},{"x":"17:52:40","y":44},{"x":"17:52:55","y":44.2},{"x":"17:53:10","y":44.5},{"x":"17:53:25","y":44.4},{"x":"17:53:40","y":44},{"x":"17:53:55","y":44.4},{"x":"17:54:10","y":44.7},{"x":"17:54:25","y":44.5},{"x":"17:54:40","y":44.4},{"x":"17:54:55","y":44.4},{"x":"17:55:10","y":44.5},{"x":"17:55:25","y":44.5},{"x":"17:55:40","y":44.4},{"x":"17:55:55","y":44.5},{"x":"17:56:10","y":44.6},{"x":"17:56:25","y":44.6},{"x":"17:56:40","y":44.6},{"x":"17:56:55","y":44.8},{"x":"17:57:10","y":44.8},{"x":"17:57:25","y":44.7},{"x":"17:57:40","y":45},{"x":"17:57:55","y":44.8},{"x":"17:58:10","y":44.8},{"x":"17:58:25","y":45.1},{"x":"17:58:40","y":45.1},{"x":"17:58:55","y":45.1},{"x":"17:59:10","y":45},{"x":"17:59:25","y":45.1},{"x":"17:59:40","y":45.1},{"x":"17:59:56","y":45},{"x":"18:00:11","y":45.4},{"x":"18:00:26","y":45.2},{"x":"18:00:41","y":45.2},{"x":"18:00:56","y":45.2},{"x":"18:01:11","y":45.2},{"x":"18:01:26","y":45.1},{"x":"18:01:41","y":45.2},{"x":"18:01:56","y":45.2},{"x":"18:02:11","y":45.4},{"x":"18:02:26","y":45.4},{"x":"18:02:41","y":45.4},{"x":"18:02:56","y":45.6},{"x":"18:03:11","y":45.7},{"x":"18:03:26","y":45.5},{"x":"18:03:41","y":45.9},{"x":"18:03:56","y":45.9},{"x":"18:04:11","y":45.6},{"x":"18:04:26","y":45.9},{"x":"18:04:41","y":46},{"x":"18:04:56","y":46.2},{"x":"18:05:11","y":46.1},{"x":"18:05:26","y":46},{"x":"18:05:41","y":46},{"x":"18:05:56","y":46.1},{"x":"18:06:11","y":46.4},{"x":"18:06:26","y":46.2},{"x":"18:06:41","y":46.5},{"x":"18:06:56","y":46.6},{"x":"18:07:11","y":46.5},{"x":"18:07:26","y":46.5},{"x":"18:07:41","y":46.5},{"x":"18:07:56","y":46.8},{"x":"18:08:11","y":46.8},{"x":"18:08:26","y":46.5},{"x":"18:08:41","y":46.9},{"x":"18:08:56","y":46.8},{"x":"18:09:11","y":47},{"x":"18:09:26","y":47.2},{"x":"18:09:41","y":47},{"x":"18:09:56","y":47.2},{"x":"18:10:11","y":47.4}],"label":"Heating return Temp (°C)","fill":true,"borderWidth":1}]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        options: {
            elements: {
                point:{
                    radius: 0
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your chart has (by default for `type: "line"`) a [category](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html) type of x axis; this is not ideal for the type of data you are plotting, for several reasons, among which the fact that the x axis distance between each two consecutive points is always the same, regardless of their time value, while your data times are not (perfectly) equidistant.

Comment: In order to have meaningful x values, you should parse the time strings and use either a [`linear`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) x axis or a [`time`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) x-axis. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/1e2b7o4f/) a suggestion on how to set up a linear axis; with that you can set your min, max and step value [as you like](https://jsfiddle.net/1e2b7o4f/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js uses a data object allows you to pass a property called `labels`. I believe you could pass an array of the times that you are wanting to be your labels there. Something like:

```
data: {
    labels: ["00:00", "06:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"],
},
```

There is also an x-axis property that you are missing it seems.

```
scales: {
    x: [{
          display: false
        },
        {
          scaleLabel: {
             display: true,
             labelString: 'frequency'
        },
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
           beginAtZero: true,
           max: 0.5,
           stepSize: 0.1
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The only thing you're going to need to do is figure out the step size that you're wanting. I'm not sure how many data points you actually have in your data. If you add the `xAxes` below that of your `yAxes` object and adjust the ticks to match the data for the values you want then that should move you in the right direction.

Comment: It only adds 00:00 https://imgur.com/MRSOrsN.png

Comment: I went ahead and expanded on some information in my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Have you tested it I also included data. For me no changes. I get and store data every 15 seconds.

Comment: If you create a codepen I'll take a look.